# YOLOv8 no prediction results

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, training-data, yolov8

Get interested in yolov8 and after few youtube tutorials i tried to train custom dataset. After all manipulations i got no prediction results :( 2nd image - val_batch0_labels, 3rd image - val_batch0_pred

[image: that's a results]
[image: val_batch0_labels]
[image: val_batch0_pred]

I tried to do this in pycharm and google colab (same results) and here's the code:

```
# main.py
from ultralytics import YOLO


model = YOLO("yolov8n.yaml")

results = model.train(data="config.yaml", epochs=1)
```

```
# config.yaml
path: Y:\coding\python\yolo_test\data_airplane\data # dataset root dir
train: images  # train images (relative to 'path')
val: images  # val images (relative to 'path')

# Classes
names:
  0: airplane
```

And for more information here's all what i get after run this:

```
              from  n    params  module                                       arguments
```

0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [3, 16, 3, 2]
1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [16, 32, 3, 2]
2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [32, 32, 1, True]
3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [32, 64, 3, 2]
4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [64, 64, 2, True]
5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 128, 3, 2]
6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [128, 128, 2, True]
7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 256, 3, 2]
8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [256, 256, 1, True]
9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.SPPF            [256, 256, 5]
10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']
11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 128, 1]
13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']
14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [192, 64, 1]
16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 64, 3, 2]
17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [192, 128, 1]
19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 128, 3, 2]
20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 256, 1]
22        [15, 18, 21]  1    897664  ultralytics.nn.modules.head.Detect           [80, [64, 128, 256]]
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3157200 parameters, 3157184 gradients

Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.141  Python-3.10.8 torch-2.0.1+cpu CPU (Intel Core(TM) i3-10105F 3.70GHz)
engine\trainer: task=detect, mode=train, model=yolov8n.yaml, data=config.yaml, epochs=1, patience=50, batch=16, imgsz=640, save=True, save_period=-1, cache=False, device=None, workers=8, project=None, name=None, exist_ok=False, pretrained=True, optimizer=auto, verbose=True, seed=0, deterministic=True, single_cls=False, rect=False, cos_lr=False, close_mosaic=10, resume=False, amp=True, fraction=1.0, profile=False, overlap_mask=True, mask_ratio=4, dropout=0.0, val=True, split=val, save_json=False, save_hybrid=False, conf=None, iou=0.7, max_det=300, half=False, dnn=False, plots=True, source=None, show=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, show_labels=True, show_conf=True, vid_stride=1, line_width=None, visualize=False, augment=False, agnostic_nms=False, classes=None, retina_masks=False, boxes=True, format=torchscript, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=False, opset=None, workspace=4, nms=False, lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=7.5, cls=0.5, dfl=1.5, pose=12.0, kobj=1.0, label_smoothing=0.0, nbs=64, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, cfg=None, tracker=botsort.yaml, save_dir=runs\detect\train22
Overriding model.yaml nc=80 with nc=1

```
               from  n    params  module                                       arguments
```

0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [3, 16, 3, 2]
1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [16, 32, 3, 2]
2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [32, 32, 1, True]
3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [32, 64, 3, 2]
4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [64, 64, 2, True]
5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 128, 3, 2]
6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [128, 128, 2, True]
7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 256, 3, 2]
8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [256, 256, 1, True]
9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.SPPF            [256, 256, 5]
10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']
11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 128, 1]
13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']
14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [192, 64, 1]
16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 64, 3, 2]
17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [192, 128, 1]
19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 128, 3, 2]
20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]
21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 256, 1]
22        [15, 18, 21]  1    751507  ultralytics.nn.modules.head.Detect           [1, [64, 128, 256]]
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3011043 parameters, 3011027 gradients

train: Scanning Y:\coding\python\yolo_test\data_airplane\data\labels.cache... 3 images, 0 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
val: Scanning Y:\coding\python\yolo_test\data_airplane\data\labels.cache... 3 images, 0 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Plotting labels to runs\detect\train22\labels.jpg...
optimizer: AdamW(lr=0.002, momentum=0.9) with parameter groups 57 weight(decay=0.0), 64 weight(decay=0.0005), 63 bias(decay=0.0)
Image sizes 640 train, 640 val
Using 0 dataloader workers
Logging results to runs\detect\train22
Starting training for 1 epochs..

```
  Epoch    GPU_mem   box_loss   cls_loss   dfl_loss  Instances       Size
    1/1         0G      3.156      3.899      4.605         33        640: 100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:02<00:00,  2.21s/it]
             Class     Images  Instances      Box(P          R      mAP50  mAP50-95): 100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:01<00:00,  1.14s/it]
               all          3         16    0.00111     0.0625   0.000607   6.07e-05
```

1 epochs completed in 0.001 hours.
Optimizer stripped from runs\detect\train22\weights\last.pt, 6.2MB
Optimizer stripped from runs\detect\train22\weights\best.pt, 6.2MB

Validating runs\detect\train22\weights\best.pt...
Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.141  Python-3.10.8 torch-2.0.1+cpu CPU (Intel Core(TM) i3-10105F 3.70GHz)
YOLOv8n summary (fused): 168 layers, 3005843 parameters, 0 gradients
Class     Images  Instances      Box(P          R      mAP50  mAP50-95): 100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:01<00:00,  1.08s/it]
all          3         16    0.00114     0.0625    0.00086    8.6e-05
Speed: 2.0ms preprocess, 123.7ms inference, 0.0ms loss, 1.7ms postprocess per image
Results saved to runs\detect\train22

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ok to get no predictions after 1 epoch of training from scratch on 3 images. The model has not learned relevant features from the data to correctly detect airplanes, so it doesn't recognize them.
If you want fast results, start your training from a pre-trained model `model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")`, it has already learned a lot of useful features from a large dataset and a long-term training process.

Also, you may need to increase the number of epochs (in this case you will see more meaningful 'results' charts), and the number of training data (in this case your model may learn something useful and not only remembers your dataset).

Check these tips for best training results: https://docs.ultralytics.com/yolov5/tutorials/tips_for_best_training_results/?h=tips